# Check if two values are coming up in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have the following data:

[image]

In the last row I want to check the uniquness of an `ISIN` number and a `date`. So if these two values are not unique in the whole table of values then I want to print 1 else 0.

I tried that:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP((A2;C2);A2:C18;1;FALSE);1;0)
```

However as you can see I get `#VALUE!`. Any suggestions how to fix that?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Am I understand you correctly that you tries to determine whether all _pairs_ ISIN and date are unique?

Comment: @simoco Yep!I try to check the `ISIN` and `date` row. If they are unique they get a `1`. If they are not unique then only one of all the events gets a `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If these two values are *not unique* in the whole table of values then I want to print 1 else 0.

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$18=A2)*($C$2:$C$18=C2))>1;1;0)
```

Comment: Hey simoco, I checked your answer back. How and why does this work? Is it also possible to add another field to the sum product formula, which basically has two values $P or S$?

Comment: 1) `($A$2:$A$18=A2)` returns array `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,...}` where true returns if cooresponding value in range `$A$2:$A$18` equals to `A2`. 2) `($C$2:$C$18=C2)` returns array `{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,...}` where true returns if cooresponding value in range `$C$2:$C$18` equals to `C2`. 3) `($A$2:$A$18=A2)*($C$2:$C$18=C2)` gives you array: `{1,0,0,0,...}` where 1 returns if corresponding value in `$A$2:$A$18` equals to A2 *AND* corresponding value in `$C$2:$C$18` equals to C2 4) Sumproduct({1,0,0,0,..}) gives you sum of thouse values

Comment: _continue..._ and if this sum is greater than 1, it means that there is more than one row with thouse values in col A and C and this pair it not unique.Not sure, I understand what condition are you going to add in columns P or S..